# HTML - Writing HTML codes in textarea

Tags: php, html

I would like to run HTML codes in textarea but it doesn't work. I get data from databese and I'm printing in a variable but codes It looks like it is, not work. How can I run HTML Codes in textarea? My Codes :

```
echo "<div id='ilkyaz'> <textarea class='metin_yazisi' id='yep' onkeypress='silyaz(event);'  readonly> $metin  </textarea> </div>";
```

`$metin's` contain is `<b> Hello </b>`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `htmlentities`

e.g.

```
echo "<div id='ilkyaz'> <textarea class='metin_yazisi' id='yep' onkeypress='silyaz(event);'  readonly>".htmlentities($metin)."</textarea> </div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use php `htmlentities()`  which will work for that

```
echo "<div id='ilkyaz'> <textarea class='metin_yazisi' id='yep' onkeypress='silyaz(event);'  readonly>".htmlentities($metin)."</textarea> </div>";
```

if you want to remove tag then use `strip_tags()`

```
echo "<div id='ilkyaz'> <textarea class='metin_yazisi' id='yep' onkeypress='silyaz(event);'  readonly>" .strip_tags($metin). " </textarea> </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CK editor Jquery Library for that .
Visit http://ckeditor.com/features for details

Comment: It's working but I have a problem, Do you have a file with no buttons on it? I would like just run html codes.